# Revisiting jQuery fader function issues

Tags: jquery, performance

creating/modifying this function, but the loop stops at the second image (of 5 total images). need help in preventing the z-index from resetting, so it will cycle through all 5 of my images instead of only the first two.

jQuery:

```
function cycleImages(){
  var $active = $('.image img');
  var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('.image img:first');
  $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
  $active.fadeOut(1500, function(){//fade out the top image
    $active.css('z-index',1).fadeIn().removeClass('image');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
    $next.css('z-index',5).addClass('image');//make the next image the top one
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".about-button, .home-button, .contact-button, .sourcing-button, .consulting-button, .installation-button").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("about-button")) {
        $(".about-container").addClass("display-flex");
    } else {
        $(".about-container").removeClass("display-flex");
    }

    if($(this).hasClass("home-button")) {
        $(".homepage-container").show();
    } else {
        $(".homepage-container").hide();
    }

    if($(this).hasClass("contact-button")) {
        $(".contact-container").addClass("display-flex");
    } else {
        $(".contact-container").removeClass("display-flex");
    }

    if($(this).hasClass("sourcing-button")) {
        $(".services-sourcing-container").addClass("display-flex");
    } else {
        $(".services-sourcing-container").removeClass("display-flex");
    }

    if($(this).hasClass("consulting-button")) {
        $(".services-consulting-container").addClass("display-flex");
    } else {
        $(".services-consulting-container").removeClass("display-flex");
    }

    if($(this).hasClass("installation-button")) {
        $(".services-installation-container").addClass("display-flex");
    } else {
        $(".services-installation-container").removeClass("display-flex");
    }
});

// run every 5s
setInterval('cycleImages()', 5000);
```

});

html:

```
<div class="fader">
    <div class="image">
        <img class="" src="images/JAJ_photo1.svg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain"; z-index="1">
    </div>
    <div class="">  
        <img class="" src="images/JAJ_photo2.svg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain"; z-index="2">
    </div>
    <div class="">  
        <img class="" src="images/JAJ_photo3.svg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain"; z-index="3">
    </div>
    <div class="">  
        <img class="" src="images/JAJ_photo4.svg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain"; z-index="4">
    </div>
    <div class="">  
        <img class="" src="images/JAJ_photo5.svg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain"; z-index="5">
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fader {
  border-radius: 1em;
  height: 25vw;
  width: 74vw;
  max-height:100%;
  min-height: 10vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1.5em solid #aa917d;
  border-right: 1.5em solid #aa917d;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fader div.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

div.image img {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: where you are calling cycleImages this function

Comment: @gayathri after all of my if/else statements in 

`$(document).ready(function(){...`

Comment: Look for [@Keyframe CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) rule

Comment: where is it the full code is not there

Comment: When you are calling this `cycleImages function`?

Comment: @jazzninja Read here:http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24794 You know you can edit your question  to show more and reformulate?

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette just did full jquery is up now

Comment: do you need more css and html as well? thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code and made some changes which are as below. Added the changes in comments within code. Few major things you just do not need in fact. Add `image` class to all the `parent-div` and each time you just need to `fadeIn/fadeOut` only particular `div`. Add an `active` class to first `div.image` by default. You can avoid all the `z-index` things with this.

**Extra CSS**

```
<!--Add below CSS just to show `div` which has active class-->

div.image:not(.active){
      display:none;  
}
```

```js
function cycleImages() {
  var $active = $('.image.active'); //get the active tab
  var $next = $active.next().length > 0 ? $active.next() : $('.image:first'); 
  //check next length if not present just get the first .image div
  //fade out the top image and remove active class from it in callback
  $active.animate({ 
    opacity:'0'
  },400,function(){
    $active.removeClass('active')
    $next.animate({ 
      opacity:'1'
    },400,function(){ 
      $next.addClass('active');
    }) 
  });
}

// run every 5s
setInterval(cycleImages, 5000);
```

```css
.fader {
  border-radius: 1em;
  height: 25vw;
  width: 74vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 10vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1.5em solid #aa917d;
  border-right: 1.5em solid #aa917d;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fader div.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
div.image img {
  z-index: 5;
}

div.image{
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 1s ease-in;
}

div.image.active{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader">
  <div class="image active">
    <img class="" src="https://images.contentful.com/256tjdsmm689/2T0QeKcvR6MSsckuKoYIwS/b57d12107fc5eb635e294ed1c76cbbac/feature-gettyimages.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain" ; z-index="1">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="" src="http://www.livemint.com/rf/Image-621x414/LiveMint/Period2/2016/04/09/Photos/DNAnocredit-kuAC--621x414@LiveMint.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain" ; z-index="2">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738CEB00000578-3504412-image-a-4_1458654503277.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain" ; z-index="3">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="" src="http://static.bigstockphoto.com/images/homepage/2016_bigstock_video.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain" ; z-index="4">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="" src="http://media.tinmoitruong.vn/public/media/media/picture/03/kh4.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain" ; z-index="5">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to cross fade them instead of `fadeOut` then `fadeIn`? The blank canvas in between images is what i'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: how do I go about implementing indicator dots within this fader that are clickable and function similarly. I.E., when the corresponding dot is clicked on, it fades to the corresponding image it is bound to? I have created the dots, and they can be converted into buttons for clickability, but how to I create a function, and what would that function be, based on the previous code you've modified above.

Comment: @jazzninja.. Please ask a different question for that.. If I answer it here, then the answer is not suitable for this particular post.. So please post a separate question..